# SPCascadedropdowns not working with lookup into same list

Tags: spcascadedropdowns

I've set up a custom new form including dropdowsns via `SPCascadedropdowns`. My site features 4 lists `Regions`, `Customers`, `Products` and `Orders`. The latter three lists include fields which are lookups as detailed in the image attached. [image: Another header]

My custom form is set up to populate the `Orders` list. It includes a javascript for dropdowns to filter `Customer name` based on selected `Customer Region` and `Product` based on selected `Customer Name`.

Now what I'm looking to do is include a further `SPCascadedropdown` for the `Previous order` field based on `Product Number` selection. The `Previous order` is a lookup into the `Order number` field in the same list (`Orders`).

The first two cascade dropdowns are working - with the caveat that the `Product` dropdown returns multiple instances of the same number. But that's to be expected for the moment and a different issue I don't want to ask here.

The third dropdown however (`Previous order`) does not work. Any idea why and I how I can get it working?

Here is my JS code:

```
var myJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

myJQ(document).ready(function() {
    myJQ().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({

    relationshipList: "Customers",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Region",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Customer_x0020_Name",
    parentColumn: "Order Region",
    childColumn: "Customer Name",
    debug: true
  });
  
   myJQ().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Orders",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Customer_x0020_Name",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Product_x0020_Number",
    parentColumn: "Customer Name",
    childColumn: "Product",
    debug: true
  });
    
  myJQ().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Orders",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Product_x0020_Number",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Product Number",
    childColumn: "Previous order",
    debug: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

JS seems to be case sensitive when it comes to field names. `Previous order` obviously is not the same as `Previous Order`.